# Splitting a row in long table in latex

Tags: longtable, overleaf

I was trying to insert a table, but as the table is very long, I used the `longtable` command. But there is a tiny space at the end of every page. Is there any way to split a single cell, thus utilizing the space properly?

Also can I shrink the table a bit so the text is still readable?

[image]

```
\def\doitems{\def\item{\par
   \noindent\hbox to1.5em{\hss$\bullet$\hss}\hangindent=1.5em }}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%literature table
\begin{longtable}{|p{.090\textwidth}|p{.050\textwidth}|p{.35\textwidth}|p{.35\textwidth}|}
\caption{Summary of Some Latest Pattern Formation Methods.}
\label{liter_comp_table}
%\begin{tabular}
%\toprule
\hline
\textbf{Method} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Methodology} & \textbf{Limitations} \\ [0.2ex]\hline
\endhead
\cite{jiang2019decentralized} & 2019 
& 
A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
& \doitems
\item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.

\item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.

 \\ [0.2ex]
```

Comment: Splitting row isn't really possible I think, but there's flushbottom.

Comment: I suggest to check, whether or not this is relevant: when using \newcommand there is an extra space UNLESS you put a % right after the last character at each end of a line. Try the same here, i.e. replace e.g.  "of other agents." by "of other agents.%" etc.

Comment: Any news? Does my answer is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

- Any (kind of) long table cannot be split in the middle of the row. It can be split only between rows.
- For lists in your table I would use `itemize` list with setings as is enabled by `enumitem` package.
- For table I would recommend to use `longtblr` table defined in the `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}%
{
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                  }
}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Summary of Some Latest Pattern Formation Methods.},
  label = {liter_comp_table},
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec={X[0.25,l] c X[j] X[j]},
                  colsep = 4pt,
                  row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                 measure = vbox,
                 rowhead = 1
                 }    
Method  & Year  & Methodology   & Limitations       \\ 
\cite{jiang2019decentralized} 
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\cite{jiang2019decentralized}
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\cite{jiang2019decentralized}
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\cite{jiang2019decentralized}
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\cite{jiang2019decentralized}
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\cite{jiang2019decentralized}
        & 2019  & A decentralized algorithm for generating a specified configuration with an arbitrary repeating pattern in a multi-robot system in two phases. Introduced a basic pattern graph to construct a basic pattern among robots then an assembling graph to assemble multiple basic patterns layer by layer until the final repeating pattern is formed.
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item The algorithm is head dependent which is responsible for maintaining the basic pattern.
                \item Each robot's movement is dependent on the initial positions of other agents.
                    \end{itemize}                   \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]